# Filter a dataframe based groupby multiple condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
name        skill          score      percentage
messi       attack         160        80
messi       fitness        10         5
messi       pass           30         15
neymar      attack         48         60
neymar      fitness        20         25
neymar      pass           12         15
ronaldo     attack         60         60
ronaldo     fitness        30         30
ronaldo     pass           10         10
casilas     attack         10         25
casilas     fitness        20         50
casilas     pass           10         25
owen        attack         20         20
owen        fitness        70         70
owen        pass           10         10
```

from the above dataframe I would like to filter `name` where `attack` `score` more than `50` and `attack` `percentage` more than `50`.

Eexpected output:

```
name        skill          score      percentage
messi       attack         160        80
messi       fitness        10         5
messi       pass           30         15
ronaldo     attack         60         60
ronaldo     fitness        30         30
ronaldo     pass           10         10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need groupby, you can use a boolean mask

```
mask = df['skill'].eq('attack') & df['score'].gt(50) & df['percentage'].gt(50)
out = df[df['name'].isin(df.loc[mask, 'name'])]

print(out)

      name    skill  score  percentage
0    messi   attack    160          80
1    messi  fitness     10           5
2    messi     pass     30          15
6  ronaldo   attack     60          60
7  ronaldo  fitness     30          30
8  ronaldo     pass     10          10
```

Comment: I would like to filter only based on attack score and attack percentage only

Comment: edited the input to make this clear

Comment: @Danish. I will update my answer soon

Comment: @Danish. Done. I added a new condition. Can you check the new solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it

```
import io
str_data="""
name,skill,score,percentage
messi,attack,160,80
messi,fitness,10,5
messi,pass,30,15
neymar,attack,48,60
neymar,fitness,20,25
neymar,pass,12,15
ronaldo,attack,60,60
ronaldo,fitness,30,30
ronaldo,pass,10,10
casilas,attack,10,25
casilas,fitness,20,50
casilas,pass,10,25
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str_data))


def filt_player(player_df):
    player_df = player_df.set_index('skill')
    
    filters = (
        player_df.loc['attack','score'] > 50,
        player_df.loc['attack','percentage'] > 50,
    )
        
    return all(filters)


filt_df = df.groupby('name').filter(filt_player)

filt_df
```